# Publishing a report including a relative path to an image file via `publish`

Tags: html, image, matlab, publish, relative-path

I've read, tested [this documentation](https://de.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/publishing-matlab-code.html) and [this example](https://de.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/marking-up-matlab-comments-for-publishing.html) and tried on my own, but have not yet found a solution for the described issue.

According to the documentation, either the image file is on the same path of the used MATLAB script, in which case one could easily add it as described

```
% <<Filename.png>>
```

or one needs to add the full path:

```
% <<C:\\Fullpath\Filename.png>>
```

otherwise one would get an empty document (at least when `publish` is creating .html files).

As the documented code should be shared I need a relative path to avoid later issues.

Is there any solution or workaround within MATLAB?

Some of my former attempts:

```
% <<.\Filename.png>>      # with and without "" or ''
% <<..\Filename.png>>     # with and without "" or ''
% <<..\..\Filename.png>>  # with and without "" or ''
```

The image does not appear.

Comment: Any possibility of using `fullpath` first, save that, then call that to display the image?

Comment: According to the page [you linked](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/marking-up-matlab-comments-for-publishing.html#btj5juu-1), you can specify a relative path for images. "_MATLAB requires that FILENAME.PNG be a relative path from the output location to your external image or a fully qualified URL._" - I'd try `% <<..\..\Filename.png>> ` or something like that.

Comment: @Adriaan I'm not sure if I understood you well? Of course I now need to use the fullpath and can generate the html file this is my actual workaround. The issue is due to some policies I shouldn't save the images in the same path. While the image file is located in a different repository which is not satisfactory.

Comment: `fullpath` is a function which retrieves the full path of the specified file. That'd solve your relative path problem, as you can call the full path on every system the code is run (i.e. it's sort-of relative anyway). What I don't know, hence my hesitationally question mark, I'm not sure how, if at all, you can use variables inside comments which should be published as HTML.

Comment: @Dev-iL if that would have worked I wouldn't have posted this question :S

Comment: Alright. Did you try it with [HTML](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/marking-up-matlab-comments-for-publishing.html#btga6k2-1)? Did you try to view the HTML of the generated report and see what sorts of image paths are generated in every attempt (and compare them to what should be there)? Maybe you need double back slashes, or forward slashes...?

Comment: @Dev-iL that sounds helpful I'll check it. First finding it looks like this: " <img vspace="5" hspace="5" src="Fullpath\Filename.png" alt=""> "

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming this directory structure:

[image]

This code,

```
function q51539865
%% Image From URL
%
% <<https://i.stack.imgur.com/zSPip.jpg>>
%

%% Image From Relative Path
%
% <<../InnerPath/zSPip.jpg>>
%
```

Produces the following web page:

[image]

When inspecting the 2<sup>nd</sup> image we see:

[image]

Comment: OMG the old slash vs backslash issue strikes back. I ask myself why I didn't think of it now seeing the link in my browser I feel somewhat ashamed for asking.

Comment: @Medi1Saif We all have those moments :)